# How do I use an SQL GROUP BY and SUM functions in a IOS CORE-DATA request in SWIFT?

Tags: sql, swift, core-data, group-by, nsfetchrequest

I have a table (Transactions) which holds records containing the Account_name and an Amount for the transaction. I would like to calculate the total for all transactions per account which start with 'Private' and for which the transaction amount is > 1000. I would like to get the accounts sorted by name, in a descending order.

So the SQL request would be something like this :

```
    SELECT Account_name, SUM(Amount) 
    FROM Transactions
    WHERE Account_name like 'Private%'
    and Amount > 1000
    GROUP BY Account_name
    ORDER BY Account_name DESC
```

How would I do this using Core-DATA in Swift.

Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Bear in mind that CoreData is not a relational database, so you should think of entities not "tables", and objects not "records".  Note also that by convention, attribute names should not begin with Uppercase letters.  That said, it is possible to construct a fetch to achieve what you want.  The key steps are:

1. create a fetch request
2. specify an `NSPredicate` to filter according to your chosen criteria
3. set the `resultType` to `.DictionaryResultType` (required for "Group By")
4. set the properties to be included in the fetch (to get the sum(), this involves creating an `NSExpression` and associated `NSExpressionDescription`).
5. set the properties to group by
6. Create an `NSSortDescriptor` to order by name, descending
7. Execute the fetch

See the following code:

```
let fetch = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Transaction")
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "Account_name like %@ AND Amount > %@", "Private*",NSNumber(double: 1000.0))
fetch.predicate = predicate
fetch.resultType = .DictionaryResultType
let sumExpression = NSExpression(format: "sum:(Amount)")
let sumED = NSExpressionDescription()
sumED.expression = sumExpression
sumED.name = "sumOfAmount"
sumED.expressionResultType = .DoubleAttributeType
fetch.propertiesToFetch = ["Account_name", sumED]
fetch.propertiesToGroupBy = ["Account_name"]
let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "Account_name", ascending: false)
fetch.sortDescriptors = [sort]
let results = managedObjectContext?.executeFetchRequest(fetch, error: nil) as NSArray?
```

The result will be an array of dictionaries, with keys "Account_name" and "sumOfAmount".

**EDIT**
To extract the value for a particular Account_name, use another predicate:

```
    let newPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "Account_name like %@", "toto")!
    if let resultsArray = results { // to unwrap the optional
        let filteredResults = resultsArray.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(newPredicate)
        let sumOfAmount = (filteredResults[0] as NSDictionary)["sumOfAmount"] as Double
    }
```

I've ignored the fact that the previous example filtered `Account_name` to those beginning "Private", and assumed you will have one (and only one) account with name "toto" (hence `filteredResults[0]`); your production code should check.

Comment: Thanks it works great. Is there now a way to get the sumOfAmount of an account. Say I want the sumOfAmount of the account named "toto" :  let sumOfAccountToto = results("toto") or let sumOfAccountToto = results["toto"]  ?

Comment: Sadly results is an array of dictionaries, not a dictionary keyed on Account_name.  To get the value for a particular account, the array must be filtered using another predicate.  I can't update my answer just now, but I will do later.