# How to calculate sum for every day in a week in Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

In my app I have some transactions added by date. Each transaction will have an `amount` field and I want to calculate the sum of all transactions for a given range, lets say, current week.

How can this be done with Core Data ?

I have thought of two ways:

1. Iterate over range of `Date` and calculate sum for each iteration
2. Use `propertiesToGroupBy` and `propertiesToFetch` from `NSFetchRequest`

Are one of this approaches good ? Or is there any other way to do this ?

Comment: Setting `propertiesToGroupBy` along with using `sum` aggregate does the work in the DB, while your app simply harvests the results. The resultant code should be easier to read as well.

Comment: Do you have an example on how to do this ? I tried to use propertiesToGroupBy, but I have to set result type to dictionary and its not working for me.

Comment: [Here is a Q&A that shows how to compute sum with `propertiesToGroupBy`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28014825/335858).

Comment: I was looking at the same thing right now. For me it doesn't work, it says: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid keypath date passed to setPropertiesToFetch:'  This is when I add the NSExpressionDescription to the propertiesToFetch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to do it like this:

```
let amountExpr = NSExpression(forKeyPath: "amount")
let sumExpr = NSExpression(forFunction: "sum:", arguments: [amountExpr])
let sumDescr = NSExpressionDescription()
sumDescr.expression = sumExpr
sumDescr.name = "sumOfAmount"
sumDescr.expressionResultType = .doubleAttributeType

let dateExpr = NSExpression(forKeyPath: "date")
let dateDescr = NSExpressionDescription()
dateDescr.expression = dateExpr
dateDescr.name = "date"
dateDescr.expressionResultType = .dateAttributeType

let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Transaction")
    request.sortDescriptors = Transaction.defaultSortDescriptors
    request.propertiesToFetch = [dateDescr, sumDescr]
    request.propertiesToGroupBy = [dateDescr]
    request.resultType = .dictionaryResultType
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    request.predicate = Transaction.rangeOfDatesPredicate(dateRange: Date.week())
let results = try! context.fetch(request) as! [NSDictionary]

for value in results {
    print(value)
}
```

Now `value` will be a dictionary with the date as key and sum as value.

***Note***: to make this work, I have to adjust the time to be the same for every date that is added to Core Data, otherwise every date will be different.

```
extension Date {
    static func current() -> Date {
        let calendar = Calendar.current

        var components = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: Date())
        components.hour = 00
        components.minute = 00
        components.second = 00

        return calendar.date(from: components)!
    }
}
```