# Core data group by and count the number of row

Tags: iphone, xcode, core-data, swift3

I am new to the core data and swift, I need to get the unique name and count of particular category which has occur in Product rows.

Here is the core data entity structure.
Product: category:String, name:String, store:String
using core data I want to execute the following sql like query

select category, count(*) as total from Product group by category order by category desc.

Please help me to get it done in swift3 with complete reference.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28014825/3985749).  It's fetching a sum rather than count, and it's the older version of Swift, but in both cases conversion should be straight forward.

Comment: @pbasdf This is fine, but my requirement is to get the count of each category in the whole table.

Comment: If you set `category` as the `propertiesToGroupBy`, and do not specify a predicate, it should give you what you need?