# How to fetch as group from Core Data with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I want you to ask something about Core Data fetch process. I am using fetch method in the below from Core Data but I need something else. Let me explain to you. I 've tried to fetch all data and filter all of it in a dictionary but it didn't work and didn't make sense to me
I have many data like

```
    Date           Price
    01.08.2018     400
    03.08.2018     600
    04.08.2018     800

    06.09.2018     1000
    11.09.2018     300
    19.09.2018     200
```

I want to fetch these data like:

Aug 2018 1800
September 2018  1500

How can i achieve of that?

Here is my fetch method

```
 func fetchLessons() -> [Lessons] {
    let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Lessons>(entityName: "Lessons")

    do {
        let lessons = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
        return lessons

    } catch let fetchErr {
        print("Failed to fetch students:", fetchErr)
        return []
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use an SQL GROUP BY and SUM functions in a IOS CORE-DATA request in SWIFT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28010110/how-do-i-use-an-sql-group-by-and-sum-functions-in-a-ios-core-data-request-in-swi)

Comment: let me check it quick Thanks in advance

Comment: Group the data into a dictionary like suggested in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52043162/how-can-i-group-fetched-dates-by-month) – the suggestions do work – and use `reduce` to sum up date values. It's pretty easy and efficient.

Comment: @vadian  Thank you for showing me to path I fetch my data as dictionary as I shared in the below

Comment: @vadian Here is My dictionary [2018-03-28 20:47:30 +0000: 750.0, 2018-08-28 20:47:44 +0000: 1500.0]

Comment: @vadian I can group that like previous question but i couldn't use  reduce function could you help me out?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I did try that answer but not worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use reduce on a dictionary that has numbers as values as in your example then do

```
let sum = dict.reduce(0, { total, item in
    total + item.value
})
```

**Update**

If you want to group by month then you can use a simple for loop to do it

```
var sumPerMonth: [String: Double] = [:]
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy MMM"

for item in dict {
    let month = formatter.string(from: item.key)
    if let value = sumPerMonth[month] {
        sumPerMonth[month] = value + item.value
    } else {
        sumPerMonth[month] = item.value
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, this helps to sum all of the dictionary results but I need to sum according to related month. That 's when I got stuck. So If you could check again question example data you would understand what I mean

Comment: @KemalEkren, I missed that but I have updated my answer